# How to DESCRIBE a TABLE in SQL ? in 8.0 version?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE dreams (
 dream_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR (20),
 type VARCHAR (10));
```

DESCRIBE dreams;

**(SHOWS AN ERROR )**

Comment: did u tried desc dreams;

Comment: what is the error message you get  ? I tried the same in dbfiddle.uk, it works perfectly fine for me. Link to [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3295de588b503a7e9c3f81b5f72e0517)

Comment: To describe table just need to type desc table name.

Comment: yes i i did Arun . It doesnt work .

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 100' at line 1 *this is the error message *

Comment: You search for `EXPLAIN` (looks like you are using `DESCRIBE` with a query - using `LIMIT 100`)?

Comment: The error appears to have nothing to do with the code posted. Where are you issuing the describe command - phpmyadmin, mysql commad line or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> desc constitution;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(2)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| constitution_name | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Please see the above example.

Answer (score 0):

> How to DESCRIBE a TABLE in SQL

The more SQL standard confirm SQL query which uses `information_schema` database and this views.

And less does the same as the non standard `desc` MySQL's clause, which was mentioned by Pawan Tiwari answer.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME AS 'Field'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_TYPE AS 'Type'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.IS_NULLABLE AS 'Null'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_KEY AS 'Key'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS 'Default'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.EXTRA AS 'Extra'
FROM 
    information_schema.TABLES
INNER JOIN
    information_schema.COLUMNS ON information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME =  information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = 'dreams'
```

**Result**

```
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dream_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     |         |       |
| type     | varchar(10) | YES  |     |         |       |
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8NTqdT6Sa52w69Uu8WTpu/0)